# Efficient 'rolling/moving hash' computation (like moving average)

Tags: c++, hash

I'm trying to optimize a program which needs to compute a hash for a constant size window in a data stream at every position (byte) of stream. It is needed for a lookup of repetitions in disk files much larger than available RAM. Currently I compute separate md5 hash for every window, but it costs a lot of time (window size is a few kilobytes, so each byte of data is processed few thousand times). I wonder if there exist a way to compute every subsequent hash in constant (window-size-independent) time (like addition and subtraction of 1 element in moving average)? The hash function may be anything as long as it gives not to long hashes (50-100 bits is ok) and its computation is reasonably fast. It also must give virtually no colisions on up to trillions of not-so-random windows (TB of data) - every collision means a disk access in my case (crc32 is much to weak, md5 is OK in this aspect).

I'll be thankful if you point me to an existing library function available on linux if there is one.

This is my first question here, so please be tolerant if I did something wrong.

regards,
bartosz

Comment: One of the properties of good hash functions (that lead to a statistically proper amount of collisions) is that their final value depends on mixing /all/ of the bits of the input data, that is in their computation in every processing step of the next chunk of data, the outcome depends on all bits that have been processed so far. If now you want to "just" leave out the first N bits, this means that the data all of the subsequent computation steps depend on is different, so all of the steps have to be redone. So you have to at least give up this strength of todays good hash functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe, is pretty near to the basic approach used in data deduplication storage.

The data deduplication systems, we usually use [Rabin's fingerprinting](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr05/cos598E/bib/broder93some.pdf) method as fast, rolling hash function.
However, while Rabin fingerprints are good and well understood collision properties, it is not cryptographically secure, i.e., there **will** be collisions. Check e.g. how [Bentley et al. used such a method in their compression method](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=755678). The question is if and how much collisions you can tolerate. If you can tolerate an occasional collision, a good Rabin fingerprint implementation might be a good idea. Good implementations can process more then 200 MB per second per core.

I am not aware of any approach with virtually no collisions (aka cryptographically secure) and rolling at the same time. As PlasmaHH, I have serious doubts that this is actually possible.

Think if you can relax your restrictions. Maybe you can allow to miss some duplicates. In these cases, faster ways are possible.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try the Rabin fingerprint metod, hope it will be good enough. I really don't want to miss more duplicates than I do (because of large block size). But maybe the cost of disk access in case of collisions will be lower than the hashing performance gain.

Comment: Rabin-Karp method indeed performs well and when implemented in 64-bit arithmetics has rare enough collisions for this task. Great thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The Wikipedia article on [rolling hashes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_hash) has a link to [ngramhashing](http://code.google.com/p/ngramhashing/) which implements a few different techniques in C++, including:

- Randomized Karp-Rabin (sometimes called Rabin-Karp)
- Hashing by Cyclic Polynomials (also known as Buzhash)
- Hashing by Irreducible Polynomials

(Also available on [GitHub](https://github.com/lemire/rollinghashcpp))

Comment: Useful link, at least I can try the existing implementations. Thanks!